# MediaElement.js disable fullscreen by doubleclick

Tags: javascript, youtube, mediaelement.js

I am using MediaElement.js to allow me to block the standard Youtube controls on my embed to prevent users from skipping through a video.  However, when you double click on the video, it gets pulled to fullscreen and then there are video controls when in fullscreen.

Basically I just want to make my users watch the video to it's full extent, but right now, all the user has to do is doubleclick the video and then use those controls to skip ahead in the video.

Does anyone know of how I can disable the doubleclick?  I have thought about just blocking users from clicking on the video, but then they can't exit out of ads or use the handy click-to-play/pause.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find solution for this?

Comment: No, i don't believe I ever did.  Haven't tried in 3 years though!